# How do I select an item from a drop down with Site Prism?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I have the following elements defined within a SitePrism page:

```
element :type, "select[id='type']"
elements :type_options, "select[id='type'] option"
```

And in my cucumber step definitions I have the following code to select an item from the select box based on the elements value:

```
@app.new.type_options.each {|name| name.click if name.text.upcase == value.upcase}
```

I don't really like this implementation but it does work perfectly when running Capybara in chrome but fails when I run it headless so I figure there must be an alternate / better way to select drop down items.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like `@app.new_r.r_type.select 'value'`, but I can't work out how to do this in SitePrism.

So, my first question is, can anyone recommend an elegant way to select an item from a drop down based on value from SitePrism?

And my second question is, any idea why the above code fails when running headless?

Comment: What do you get when you try `@app.new_r.r_type.select 'value'` ?

Comment: I get a Unable to find option "event" (Capybara::ElementNotFound) error.

Comment: Correction - I had tried this before but I was trying to match 'value' with 'Value' and was getting an Unable to find option "event" (Capybara::ElementNotFound) error. After fixing my matchers this is now working. This has also solved my second issue. Thanks Nat!

Comment: If you could write up an answer to this question for the benefit of future googlers that would be great! :)

Comment: OK. So to fix this i had to do 2 things. First was follow Nat's suggestion and use 
@app.new_r.r_type.select 'value' 
to select an item from the drop down box based on its value. The second thing I needed to do was change the capybara default driver and the javascript driver to webkit - 
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit. 
Not sure why that was necessary as no javascript was being used on the offending page, but hey ho, it works now!

Comment: Cool. Now if you could make that an *actual* 'answer' (ie: copy and paste the above into what stackoverflow considers an answer) that would be even better :)

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem, where I couldn't get it to select the option I wanted. I came across this question and it made me realize my problem was that you have to send the text, not the value, to the select().

For example, if I have HTML like

```
<select id="things">
  <option value="thing1">The First Thing</option>
  <option value="thing2">The Second Thing</option>
  <option value="thing3">The Third Thing</option>
</select>
```

And in my SitePrism::Page class I have:

```
element :things, "select[id='things']"
```

I thought I needed to do:

```
@my_page.things.select("thing1")
```

That does not work.  Instead you have to do:

```
@my_page.things.select("The First Thing")
```

I know this is slightly different than trying to select based on a value you get from SitePrism, like was originally asked.  But I thought this distinction about what to pass to select() might help someone.